# bitbucket pipeline with laravel & shared hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, bitbucket-pipelines

i am trying to deploy laravel 5.4 app with bitbucket pipeline and get eror 
"fatal: Could not get last commit. Network down? Wrong URL? Use 'git ftp init' for the inital push., exiting..."

i read an article on this [site](https://www.savjee.be/2016/06/Deploying-website-to-ftp-or-amazon-s3-with-BitBucket-Pipelines/)

i create this yaml file

`image: samueldebruyn/debian-git`

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://site.com

and got eror 
**git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD site_url
fatal: Could not get last commit. Network down? Wrong URL? Use 'git ftp init' for the inital push., exiting...**

Comment: At-least explain the process shortly, Reading article will be a bit difficult.

Comment: @Comrade i update the description.

Answer (score 0):

some hosting provider don't allow external app and block all port just open 80 and 4 more for ftp ssl and ssh if you want to deploy your laravel in share hosting just upload all your data to root except public folder and than upload all data of public folder to your index folder www or public_html 
here is screenshot of example
[image]